# How to launch LibGDX game from native iOS view controller?

Tags: libgdx

I need to launch a libgdx game from within a native GUI for both iOS and Android.  For android I can use libgdx’s initializeForView, which I believe allows me to launch a game from a view and place the game’s GLSurfaceView on a custom view or GUI element.

For iOS, is there a way do something similar and receive the UIView that the game will play in, such that it can be placed into a UIViewController manually?